# TSQL where case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need the correct tsql syntax for this problem :

```
Select * from table where var_A='10'
select * from table where var_B='10'
```

When to use var_A or var_B depends on the value of var_C

So when `var_c='something'` use `var_A='10'` else `var_B='10'`

Comment: consider changing the layout of your tables. Your problem indicates a heavy design flaw. Would you mind to show your table design or explain what the table contains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select *
from [table]
where case when var_c = 'something' then var_a else var_b end = '10'
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45759/1).

Answer (score 2):

Ian probably has the best answer available but I thought I would supply another answer for a different (although less flexible) method in case it helps:

```
IF var_c = 'something' BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE var_a = '10'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE var_b = '10'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This how you use case statement within where clause.

```
select * from table
where ( case when var_c = 'something' 
        then var_a
        else 
            var_b
        end
      )
```